Angular 17 - cdk drag-drop - (cdkDropListDropped) event is only fired once
I'm working on a nestedTree on angular 17 with drag and drop api from angular material
this the html part of the component :
<mat-tree [dataSource]="categories" [treeControl]="treeControl" class="fb-tree">
<mat-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let category" matTreeNodeToggle matTreeNodePadding
    [ngClass]="{' border-t ': treeMode === 'INTERNAL'}">
    @if(treeMode === " INTERNAL"){
    <div class=" uppercase" cdkDropList [id]="getCategoryCode(category)" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)"
        [cdkDropListData]="nodeCategoryList">
        <div class=" grid grid-cols-2 gap-0">
            <div class="grid grid-cols-8">
                @if(hasEmojiAndRank(category)){
                <div *ng-if="hasEmojiAndRank(category)" class=" justify-start items-start w-1/6 self-center"
                    [class.ml-11]="isRoot(category)">
                    {{ category.emoji }}
                </div>

                <div class=" justify-start items-start w-1/6 self-center" [class.ml-2]="!isRoot(category)"
                    [class.ml-12]="isRoot(category)">
                    {{ category.rank }}
                </div>}

                <div class=" justify-start items-start w-4/6  uppercase" [class.ml-10]="isRoot(category)"
                    [class.ml-1.5]="!isRoot(category)">
                    {{ category.code }}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="group flex relative justify-end">
                <button mat-icon-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu" aria-label=" icon-button with a menu">
                    <mat-icon>more_vert</mat-icon>
                </button>
                <mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
                    <button mat-menu-item (click)="addNewItem.emit(category)">
                        <mat-icon>add</mat-icon>
                        <span>Add Category</span>
                    </button>
                    <button mat-menu-item (click)="editItem.emit(category)">
                        <mat-icon>edit</mat-icon>
                        <span>Edit</span>
                    </button>
                    <button mat-menu-item (click)="removeItem.emit(category)">
                        <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
                        <span>Delete</span>
                    </button>
                </mat-menu>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ml-10">
            <mat-chip-set #chipGrid>
                @for (ex of category.partners; track ex.entries) {
                @for (value of ex[1]; track value) {
                <mat-chip class="uppercase" (removed)="chipRemoved(category, value, ex[0])">
                    [{{ ex[0] }}] {{ value }}
                    <button matChipRemove [attr.aria-label]="'remove ' + value">
                        <mat-icon>cancel</mat-icon>
                    </button>
                </mat-chip>
                }}
            </mat-chip-set>
        </div>
    </div>
    }@else {
    <div cdkDropList CdkDragStart [id]="buildPartnerId(category)" [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="nodeCategoryList"
        (cdkDropListDropped)="partnerDrop($event)" (cdkDragStarted)="startDrag(category)"
        [cdkDropListData]="nodeCategoryList">
        <div cdkDrag class="w-max h-max">{{ category.code }}</div>
    </div>
    }

</mat-tree-node>

<mat-nested-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let category; when: hasChild" matTreeNodePadding>
    @if(treeMode === "INTERNAL"){
    <div class="flex flex-col" cdkDropList id="{{ category.code }}" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)"
        [cdkDropListData]="nodeCategoryList">
        <div class="mat-tree-node grid grid-cols-2 gap-0 border-t">
            <div class="grid grid-cols-8">
                <div class="flex flex-col justify-start items-start w-1/6 mr-10">
                    <button mat-icon-button matTreeNodeToggle [attr.aria-label]="'Toggle ' + category.code">
                        <mat-icon class="mat-icon-rtl-mirror">
                            {{ treeControl.isExpanded(category) ? 'expand_more' : 'chevron_right' }}
                        </mat-icon>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="flex flex-col justify-start items-start w-1/6 ml-2 self-center">
                    {{ category.emoji }}
                </div>
                <div class="flex flex-col justify-start items-start w-1/6 self-center ml-3">
                    {{ category.rank }}
                </div>

                <div class="flex flex-col justify-start items-start ml-1 w-5/6 self-center">
                    {{ category.code }}
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="group flex relative justify-end">
                <button mat-icon-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu" aria-label=" icon-button with a menu">
                    <mat-icon>more_vert</mat-icon>
                </button>
                <mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
                    <button mat-menu-item (click)="addNewItem.emit(category)">
                        <mat-icon>add</mat-icon>
                        <span>Add Category</span>
                    </button>
                    <button mat-menu-item (click)="editItem.emit(category)">
                        <mat-icon>edit</mat-icon>
                        <span>Edit</span>
                    </button>
                    <button mat-menu-item (click)="removeItem.emit(category)">
                        <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
                        <span>Delete</span>
                    </button>
                </mat-menu>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ml-10">
            <mat-chip-set #chipGrid>
                @for (ex of category.partners; track ex.entries) {
                @for (value of ex[1]; track value) {
                <mat-chip class="uppercase" (removed)="chipRemoved(category, value, ex[0])">
                    [{{ ex[0] }}] {{ value }}
                    <button matChipRemove [attr.aria-label]="'remove ' + value">
                        <mat-icon>cancel</mat-icon>
                    </button>
                </mat-chip>
                }}
            </mat-chip-set>
        </div>
    </div>
    }@else {
    <div class="mat-tree-node" cdkDropList id="{{ category.code }}">
        <button mat-icon-button matTreeNodeToggle [attr.aria-label]="'Toggle ' + category.code">
            <mat-icon class="mat-icon-rtl-mirror">
                {{ treeControl.isExpanded(category) ? 'expand_more' : 'chevron_right' }}
            </mat-icon>
        </button>
        <div cdkDropList [id]="buildPartnerId(category)" [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="nodeCategoryList"
            (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)" [cdkDropListData]="nodeCategoryList">
            <div cdkDrag class="w-max h-max">{{ category.code }}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    }

    <div [class.fb-tree-invisible]="!treeControl.isExpanded(category)" role="group">
        <ng-container matTreeNodeOutlet></ng-container>
    </div>
</mat-nested-tree-node>

and for TS part I have :
export class FbTreeComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  @Input() categories = new MatTreeNestedDataSource<Category>();
  @Input() partnerCategories!: PartnerCategory[];
  @Input() treeControl = new NestedTreeControl<Category>((node) => node.children);
  @Input() treeMode: string;
  @Input() nodeCategoryList!: string[];
  @Output() dropCategory = new EventEmitter<CdkDragDrop<string[]>>();
  @Output() partnerDropCategory = new EventEmitter<CdkDragDrop<string[]>>();
  @Output() addNewItem = new EventEmitter<Category>();
  @Output() editItem = new EventEmitter<Category>();
  @Output() removeItem = new EventEmitter<Category>();
  @Output() removeChip = new EventEmitter<any>();

  constructor(
    private cd: ChangeDetectorRef,
    private localStorageService: LocalStorageService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(this.categories);
  }

  hasChild = (_: number, node: Category) => !!node.children && node.children.length > 0;

  isRoot(node: Category): boolean {
    return !node.children || node.children.length === 0; // or another condition that defines a root node
  }

  drop(event: CdkDragDrop<any>) {
    this.dropCategory.emit(event);
  }

I have divided the screen into two parts: there are two trees, one on the left and the other on the right. I want to drag nodes from the right tree to the left tree.
My problem is with the first node of the tree when it is dropped on the left side. The first drop works fine, but after that, no events are triggered for subsequent drops. However, I can still drop nodes onto other nodes that are on the same level (not children).
I have tried debugging various types of events to see if any of them work, but none of them fire for the first element after the initial drop.
I'm not sure if something happens during the first drag that deactivates events for that container. I did verify the DOM and noticed that there are no changes to the IDs, and no classes are added or removed.
Add :
not only after the first drop but afetr any event fired from the first node

problem solved :
i was not using the idrectives cdkDrag and cdkDropList correctly
here is teh new version for HTML part for anyone get same problem :
<mat-tree [dataSource]="categories" [treeControl]="treeControl" class="fb-tree">
<mat-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let category" matTreeNodeToggle matTreeNodePadding
    [ngClass]="{' border-t ': treeMode === 'INTERNAL'}">
    @if(treeMode === " INTERNAL"){
    <div class=" uppercase" cdkDropList [id]="getCategoryCode(category)" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)"
        [cdkDropListData]="nodeCategoryList">
        <div class=" grid grid-cols-2 gap-0">
            <div class="grid grid-cols-8">

                <div class=" justify-start items-start w-1/6 self-center" [class.ml-11]="isRoot(category)">
                    {{ category.emoji }}
                </div>

                <div class=" justify-start items-start w-1/6 self-center" [class.ml-2]="!isRoot(category)"
                    [class.ml-12]="isRoot(category)">
                    {{ category.rank }}
                </div>

                <div class=" justify-start items-start w-4/6  uppercase" [class.ml-10]="isRoot(category)"
                    [class.ml-1.5]="!isRoot(category)">
                    {{ category.code }}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="group flex relative justify-end">
                <button mat-icon-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu" aria-label=" icon-button with a menu">
                    <mat-icon>more_vert</mat-icon>
                </button>
                <mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
                    <button mat-menu-item (click)="addNewItem.emit(category)">
                        <mat-icon>add</mat-icon>
                        <span>Add Category</span>
                    </button>
                    <button mat-menu-item (click)="editItem.emit(category)">
                        <mat-icon>edit</mat-icon>
                        <span>Edit</span>
                    </button>
                    <button mat-menu-item (click)="removeItem.emit(category)">
                        <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
                        <span>Delete</span>
                    </button>
                </mat-menu>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ml-10">
            <mat-chip-set #chipGrid>
                @for (ex of category.partners; track ex.entries) {
                @for (value of ex[1]; track value) {
                <mat-chip class="uppercase" (removed)="chipRemoved(category, value, ex[0])">
                    [{{ ex[0] }}] {{ value }}
                    <button matChipRemove [attr.aria-label]="'remove ' + value">
                        <mat-icon>cancel</mat-icon>
                    </button>
                </mat-chip>
                }}
            </mat-chip-set>
        </div>
    </div>
    }@else {
    <div cdkDropList [id]="buildPartnerId(category)" [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="nodeCategoryList">
        <div cdkDrag class="w-max h-max">{{ category.code }}</div>
    </div>
    }

</mat-tree-node>

<mat-nested-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let category; when: hasChild" matTreeNodePadding>
    @if(treeMode === "INTERNAL"){
    <div class="flex flex-col" cdkDropList id="{{ category.code }}" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)"
        [cdkDropListData]="nodeCategoryList">
        <div class="mat-tree-node grid grid-cols-2 gap-0 border-t">
            <div class="grid grid-cols-8">
                <div class="flex flex-col justify-start items-start w-1/6 mr-10">
                    <button mat-icon-button matTreeNodeToggle [attr.aria-label]="'Toggle ' + category.code">
                        <mat-icon class="mat-icon-rtl-mirror">
                            {{ treeControl.isExpanded(category) ? 'expand_more' : 'chevron_right' }}
                        </mat-icon>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="flex flex-col justify-start items-start w-1/6 ml-2 self-center">
                    {{ category.emoji }}
                </div>
                <div class="flex flex-col justify-start items-start w-1/6 self-center ml-3">
                    {{ category.rank }}
                </div>

                <div class="flex flex-col justify-start items-start ml-1 w-5/6 self-center">
                    {{ category.code }}
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="group flex relative justify-end">
                <button mat-icon-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu" aria-label=" icon-button with a menu">
                    <mat-icon>more_vert</mat-icon>
                </button>
                <mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
                    <button mat-menu-item (click)="addNewItem.emit(category)">
                        <mat-icon>add</mat-icon>
                        <span>Add Category</span>
                    </button>
                    <button mat-menu-item (click)="editItem.emit(category)">
                        <mat-icon>edit</mat-icon>
                        <span>Edit</span>
                    </button>
                    <button mat-menu-item (click)="removeItem.emit(category)">
                        <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
                        <span>Delete</span>
                    </button>
                </mat-menu>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ml-10">
            <mat-chip-set #chipGrid>
                @for (ex of category.partners; track ex.entries) {
                @for (value of ex[1]; track value) {
                <mat-chip class="uppercase" (removed)="chipRemoved(category, value, ex[0])">
                    [{{ ex[0] }}] {{ value }}
                    <button matChipRemove [attr.aria-label]="'remove ' + value">
                        <mat-icon>cancel</mat-icon>
                    </button>
                </mat-chip>
                }}
            </mat-chip-set>
        </div>
    </div>
    }@else {
    <div class="mat-tree-node" id="{{ category.code }}">
        <button mat-icon-button matTreeNodeToggle [attr.aria-label]="'Toggle ' + category.code">
            <mat-icon class="mat-icon-rtl-mirror">
                {{ treeControl.isExpanded(category) ? 'expand_more' : 'chevron_right' }}
            </mat-icon>
        </button>
        <div cdkDropList cdkDrag [id]="buildPartnerId(category)" [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="nodeCategoryList">
            <div class="w-max h-max">{{ category.code }}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    }

    <div [class.fb-tree-invisible]="!treeControl.isExpanded(category)" role="group">
        <ng-container matTreeNodeOutlet></ng-container>
    </div>
</mat-nested-tree-node>

